# alternate method of datatable to get the value instead of using tostring()

Tags: c#, datatable

i want to get the Column value of datatable in a string type variable ,i am using this code.

```
objdt.Rows[i]["mr_mdi_meter_status_3"].ToString();
```

someone said to me dont use tostring() method it will convert every value to string.
he said right! but what is another way to get the value from datatable col?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the value contain in the object to the type you are expecting using the Convert class. For example you have a column containing int you can use [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx) directly and pass the object containing the int. This wont require you to convert the value to string using `ToString` method.

```
int meterStatus = Convert.ToInt32(objdt.Rows[i]["mr_mdi_meter_status_3"]);
```

Other possiblity is to use Typed DataSet, read the MSDN article [HOW TO: Create and Use a Typed DataSet by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714) for understanding how Typed DataSet could be used.